# Bootstrap Navbar dropdown not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

This is a part of code from my nav bar. I am trying to create a dropdown menu, but unfortunately on mobile  when i click the toggle instead of showing dropdown it closed . I have tried to update all the stylesheet bootstrap code , and link . i have tried other models on navbar dropdown but the same thing

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
        <img src="assets/images/mindnmovelogo.png" alt="Logo">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="toggler-icon"></span>
        <span class="toggler-icon"></span>
        <span class="toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse sub-menu-bar" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul id="nav" class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="page-scroll" href="#home">INDUSTRIES</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">WHO WE ARE</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="page-scroll nav-link " href="#" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"
                    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i>WHAT WE DO</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="page-scroll" href="#footer">GET IN TOUCH</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div> <!-- navbar collapse -->

    <div class="navbar-btn d-none d-sm-inline-block">
        <a class="main-btn" data-scroll-nav="0" href="mailto:">GET A FREE QUOTE</a>
    </div>
</nav> <!-- navbar -->
```

Comment: "when i click the toggle instead of showing dropdown it closed" is a little unclear because It's initially closed. If it's not interacting at all (check the 'collapse'  class on button is toggling) you might be missing jquery.

Comment: can you provide the working link

Comment: @devdev_dev the navbar collapse is working with regular one, but when i added the dropdown menu, its not working on mobile, so since the regular one is working on desktop, it means jQuery is ok